# MongoDB filter by nested

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I need to filter data in mongoDB based multiple properties from nested elem

my document:

```
item: {
items: [
    id: 1
    prop: "asd",
    elems: [
        {
            id: 111,
            isActive: true
        },
        {
            id: 222,
            isActive: true          
        }
    ]
]


{
item: {
items: [
    id: 2
    prop: "asd",
    elems: [
        {
            id: 111,
            isActive: false
        },
        {
            id: 444,
            isActive: true          
        }
    ]
]
```

if I send id 111 i need to get all items with elems contain id 111 but isActive true

Comment: Please, provide a valid JSON format.

Comment: This should help you out https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.collection.find({
  items: {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "elems": {
        "$elemMatch": {
          id: 111,
          isActive: true
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

example : https://mongoplayground.net/p/zl17zmuoe9g